# Specific Order for "for-Loop" Incrementation

Tags: c, for-loop, iteration, external

by standard I use

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{...do something...}
```

But I often iterate throu Strings in C (char[]), exspecially by creating shift-loops for lcd-displays i have to store the first char and put it at the end after shifting.

Therefor my question is:
Can I change the order so something like that (I know that this is wrong CODE!!):

```
uint8_t i;
for(i++;i=0; i<10;)
{...do something...}
uint8_t last_iterated_value = i;
```

The problem in normal style is, that the condition "i<10" will terminate the loop with 9 but the following i++ makes the i in the loop and after the loop different.

In other words, I want to see the last valid value of i in "{...}" direkt after the loop.
And of course i know, that I can decrement the "i" again.
I am just curious if there is a way to let the for-loop end with the query.

Thanks a lot...

Greatings Oekel

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?  Like a list of `i` values with order you want to `do something` on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following is valid

```
uint8_t last_iterated_value = i-1;
```

You can use also

```
int i=0;
do {
    ...do something...
} while(i<10);
uint8_t last_iterated_value = i;
```

Or

```
int i=-1;
while(++i<10) {
    ...do something...
}
uint8_t last_iterated_value = i;
```

Comment: **I totaly forgot the do{}while()-Loop**
I think this is the naturaliest way of writing what I exspected.
The solution with an closing "break" at the end of the for()-loop, is my 2. choise **BUT** it needs a extra if(i==9)-clausel to get sure the loop ends not too early.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<=SENTINEL_VALUE; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
```

or, after the loop, make take `i - 1` as `last_iterated _value`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword `break` to exit the loop without incrementing the `i`.

```
uint8_t i;
for(i++;i=0; i<10;){
...do something...
break;
}
uint8_t last_iterated_value = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the order of the items in the for statement and expect them to do the same thing.  I think what you want is this:

```
int last_i;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  ....do stuff ...
  last_i = i; //put this inside the loop instead of after
}
```

Or even this:

```
int last_i;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++, last_i = i-1)
{
  ....do stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I entirely follow your question. But, if the idea is to capture the value of `i` that was actually used in an iteration, then you should probably capture it within the loop itself.

In the simplest case, you can set it in the increment part of the `for` loop like so:

```
int last_iterated_value = -1;
for(int i=0; i<10; last_iterated_value = i++)
{...do something...}
```

However, in the case that there is an early break from the `for` loop, only you can decide if the value being used at the time the `break` condition is detected whether the value of `i` should be used as the last iterated value or not.

Answer (score 0):

please call this on a `main()` and see if i understood your question right

```
void *workin(){
    int i=0,count=10;

    char v[]={' ',' ','>','>','>',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
    printf("\n");
    for(;;){
        for(i=count-1;i>=0;i--){
            v[(i+1)%(count)]=v[i];
        }
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("processing %s \r",v);
        sleep(1);

    }
}
```